# Is there an easy way to prepare Fortran code for parallel invocation

Tags: memory-management, parallel-processing, fortran, openmp

I want to solve multiple large ODE systems in a C++ program in parallel using OpenMP. For certain reasons I need to use an ODE solver for which I could only find a Fortran 90 subroutine, and the code is too large to simply translate it to C.

I know that Fortran uses static memory extensively and that I therefore have to prime the code for parallel invocations; but I am not really familiar with the language so:

- Is there a standard (automated) solution for my problem?
- Which parts of the code do I have to modify?

The second question boils down to: How and when does Fortran allocate and free memory for variables and (how) does it reuse memory from function arguments?

So far, I've already found out that `COMMON` sections correspond to global variables in C, but can be made thread-local using Fortran's OpenMP directive `!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(/…/)`. Is this correct? What about other local variables? They are statically allocated, too, right? What is the easiest way to tell Fortran to allocate them dynamically? Should I use the `ALLOCATE` statement, or does the `RECURSIVE` keyword, resp. gfortran's `-frecursive`, help, or is there some way to just pass a large chunk of memory from C++ and let Fortran use that for all its variables? (`EQUIVALENCE`?) OpenMP's `THREADPRIVATE` always allocates from the heap, so I wouldn't want to use it for all local variables – correct?

Comment: Have you looked at [GSL's ODE integrators](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Stepping-Functions.html#Stepping-Functions)?

Comment: Thanks, but I need a high-order implicit integrator and already ruled out BDF, so GSL is not an option.

Comment: If someone else has similar problems: Note that in gfortran and non-free form, the OpenMP directives have to be placed in the first column. gfortran does _not_ issue a warning if the directives are placed in col 7, but interprets the line as a comment. Took me a while to figure that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard doesn't talk about anything like static memory, heap or stack. If you use`recursive` or a compiler option that forces it, then you can be sure every copy of the subroutine uses their own copy of the variables, unless they are `save`. They will be typically on the stack. If you do not use `recursive` the compiler is free to use the static memory. Most often it uses the stack, but you cannot rely on it. BTW, in `gfortran` compiler using `-fopenmp` implies `-frecursive` automatically.

Beware! Every variable that is explicitly initialized is `save` implicitly!

```
real :: ivar = 1
```

is such an example. The initialization using `DATA` has the same effect. This variable will not be thread-safe, unless you remove the initialization or use `threadprivate`.

For dynamic allocation, use `allocate` of course. It is safe. Each openmp thread will allocate it's own variables and arrays.

The `threadprivate` directive is indeed useful, as you found out yourself. I am not sure whether you can guarantee it will use the stack or the heap, but the heap is more likely as they have to remain in scope throughout the execution.

Not only `common` corresponds to C globals. Also module variables do. They are also `save` implicitly.

Comment: The code uses implicit definitions. Do such variables also count as explicitly initialized when they are first used in a const assignment (i.e. `i = 1`)? To be on the safe side, I used a script to add `IMPLICIT NONE` at the top of each subroutine and then repeatedly try to compile & add the correct definition plus a `threadprivate` directive for each error message, until there are no errors left. So I now have `threadprivate` for each local variable and common block, no explicit initializations, no `save` and no modules. Did I miss anything or should this work?

Comment: No, if the value is assigned in an executable statement, they are regular variables. If `DATA` statement is used, it is the initialization that implies `save`. I would say having `threadprivate` for every variable is overkill and after your code works, you should see you can remove it from most of the local variables - the non-saved ones.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that it does not work – unless I set `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1` or replace the Fortran code with a C solver. I wanted to make sure that everything _should_ be correct on the Fortran side before digging into the code to find the problem's source… Since I know that now I'll mark this as resolved, thanks again!

Comment: If you have access to tools such as Oracle Thread Analyzer, Intel Inspector and their respective compilers, I strongly suggest to try them. I had great results in identifying race conditions in my codes with them. Also helgrind can be used for GCC, but must be compiled in a special way for OpenMP.