# Fortran OpenMP with subroutines and functions

Tags: fortran, thread-safety, openmp

Disclaimer:  I'm quite certain that this has been answered somewhere, but myself and another person have been searching quite hard to no avail.

I've got a code that looks something like this:

```
      PROGRAM main
!$omp parallel do
!$omp private(somestuff) shared(otherstuff)
      DO i=1,n
        ...
        CALL mysubroutine(args)
        ...
        a=myfunction(moreargs)
        ...
      ENDDO
!$omp end parallel do
      END PROGRAM
      SUBROUTINE mysubroutine(things)
      ...
      END SUBROUTINE
      FUNCTION myfunction(morethings)
      ...
      END FUNCTION
```

I cannot determine where/how to handle private, shared, reduction, etc. clauses for the variables in the subroutine and function.  I suspect there may be some nuances to the answer, as there are many, many ways variables might have been declared and shared amongst them.  So, let's say all variables that the main program are concerned with were defined in it or in shared modules, and that any OMP operations on those variables can be handled in the main code.  The subroutines and functions use some of those variables, and have some of their own variables.  So, *I think* the question boils down to how to handle clauses for their local variables.

Comment: Show an example of such a function. If the local variables are not `save`, they are not a problem.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22381795/is-there-an-easy-way-to-prepare-fortran-code-for-parallel-invocation  They keywords you want to research is *thread-safety* and *thread-safe* procedures.

Comment: @VladimirF to clarify, I have the code for the other two, so it is more a question of syntax than thread safety.  `SAVE` is in the mix, both the subroutine and function get called a LOT, so avoiding unnecessary repeated memory allocations is important.  Though, if using `SAVE` bumps them over to the heap, (and hurts performance), then it's not worthwhile.  Testing may be in order.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your whole question is about thread-safety, isn't it? What kind of syntax you have in mind? You cannot access variables which are not in scope. If you have the code, show it! Otherwise your question is too broad.

Comment: Am still reading up.  I had thought that I needed to, e.g., put `!$omp private()` statements in the subroutine, I now get why my last comment was nonsensical.  That OMP doesn't descend into subroutines/functions greatly simplifies things, and it seems like just assigning the routines as `recursive` can guarantee safety.

Comment: I'm not sure from your comment, but if you declare variables with `SAVE` in procedures called from an OpenMP parallel region, you are likely to have conflicts between threads.   You can use OpenMP directives in those subroutines: the term for such usage is "orphaned".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, this is about the difference between the lexical and dynamic extent of OpenMP directives and the interaction with variable scoping. The lexical extent of a directive is the text between the beginning and the end of the structured block following a directive. The dynamic extent is the lexical extent *plus* statements executed as part of any subprogram executed as a result of statements in the lexical extent. So in something like

```
Program stuff
   Implicit None
   Real, Dimension( 1:100 ) :: a
   Call Random_number( a )
   !$omp parallel default( none ) shared( a )
   Call sub( a )
   !$omp end parallel
Contains
   Subroutine sub( a )
      Real, Dimension( : ), Intent( InOut ) :: a
      Integer :: i
      !$omp do
      Do i = 1, Size( a )
         a( i ) = 2.0 * a( i )
      End Do
   End Subroutine Sub
End Program stuff
```

(totally untested, written direct in here) the lexical extent of the parallel region initiated by !$omp parallel is just

```
   Call sub( a )
```

while the dynamic extent is the call *and* the contents of the subroutine. And for completeness of terminology the !$omp do is an example of an orphaned directive, a directive that is not in the lexical extent of another directive, but in the dynamic extent. See

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#Scoping

for another example.

Why does this matter? Well you can only explicitly scope variables for entities in the lexical scope, just the array a in this case, but for entities that become defined due to the dynamic extent being executed you can't do this! Instead OpenMP has a number of rules, which in simple terms are

1. The scope of subprogram arguments is inherited from the calling point, i.e. if you scoped them as private at the start of the lexical extent they stay private, and if shared they stay shared
2. Local variables to subprograms are by default private (so i in the above is private, as you want) unless they are declared with the SAVE attribute (either explicitly or implicitly) in which case they are shared.

And in my experience that gets you most of the way! Use of the dynamic extent combined with orphaned directives is a great way to keep an OpenMP program under control, and I have to say I disagree with the above comment, I find orphaned workshare directives very useful indeed! So you can combine all of the above to do things like

```
Program dot_test
  Implicit None
  Real, Dimension( 1:100 ) :: a, b
  Real :: r
  a = 1.0
  b = 2.0
  !$omp parallel default( none ) shared( a, b, r )
  Call dot( a, b, r )
  Write( *, * ) r
  !$omp end parallel
Contains
  Subroutine dot( a, b, r )
    Real, Dimension( : ), Intent( In    ) :: a, b
    Real,                 Intent(   Out ) :: r
    Real, Save :: s
    Integer :: i
    !$omp single
    s = 0.0
    !$omp end single
    !$omp do reduction( +:s )
    Do i = 1, Size( a )
       s = s + a( i ) * b( i )
    End Do
    !$omp end do
    !$omp single
    r = s
    !$omp end single
  End Subroutine dot
End Program dot_test
Wot now? gfortran -std=f95 -fopenmp -O -Wall -Wextra dot.f90 
Wot now? export OMP_NUM_THREADS=3
Wot now? ./a.out
   200.000000    
   200.000000    
   200.000000
```

This simple situation is a bit complicated by module variables and common blocks, so don't use global variables ... but if you must they are by default shared unless declared as threadprivate. See

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#THREADPRIVATE

for an example.

Comment: Nice example, I was wrong. The treatment of the `save` variable you show is also useful. There is a nice discussion about orphaned directives in Chandra's Parallel Programming in OpenMP.