# Using openmp to find maximum value in more than one loop

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have three Do loops over three parameters and I want to use openmp to speed up the calculation to find the maximum value of F as a function of A and eventually plot F_max vs A.  Here is my attempt that only uses multiple cores at the start but then falls off to one. If I leave out the critical statement it doesn't produce the correct max value.  How can I get this to work properly? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
PROGRAM maxfunction
    Do i=0, n1
        A= i*1.0
        Max=0
        Do j=0, n2
            B=j*1.0
            Do k=0,n3
                C=k*1.0
                F=findF(A,B,C)
                 If( F > Max) Then 
                     Max= F
                 endif
            Enddo
        Enddo
    Enddo 
ENDPROGRAM

FUNCTION findF(a,b,c)
    findF= g1(a,b,c) + g2(a,b,c) +g3(a,b,c)
    !returns value of findF
ENDFUNCTION findF

function g1(a,b,c)
    !do stuff with a,b,c
    !returns value g1
endfunction g1

function g2(a,b,c)
    !do stuff with a,b,c
    !returns value g2
endfunction g2

function g3(a,b,c)
    !do stuff with a,b,c
    !returns value g3
endfunction g3
```

The code has this minimal structure.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the welcome [tour] and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: Always tell us what is the correct value you expect, which value you get instead and make the code you shpw testable so that we can actually get the same value. See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Note that the function `F` is also important and you should supply its code. Make sure it is thread-safe.

Comment: I'd be a little worried about `F=F(A,B,C)`.

Comment: @Vladimir, without the full code, it is difficult to determine if `F` is a function.  The line `F = F(A,B,C)` looks like an array assignment unless the do-loop are within a recursive function `F`.

Comment: Hi, F calls a function that is within a module that contains other functions and subroutines to help calculate F. It is dependent on a, b, c

Comment: So I was a little sloppy in writing the above code. I was trying to make it easier to understand. There's a function like "function f(a,b,c) " that takes a b and c as inputs and returns F

Comment: Ok, but now there is no OpenMP in it. Please notice the *verifiable*  in the link above. We should be able to replicate your problem.

Comment: omp  reduction(max: works both with the sort of code you quote as well as with the more idiomatic Fortran max() intrinsic.  You said you were interested in performance, so you would take care that the inner loop code is implemented as simd reduction.  This may require an  inner loop simd reduction variable separate from the outer loop parallel reduction variable.

Comment: Without a complete code it is difficult to tell exactly what you are trying to do (and please, even in toy code, always use Implicit None), but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347944/fortran-openmp-with-subroutines-and-functions/35361665#35361665 might be of use

Answer (score 0):

You can try adapting the following code. Hope it helps. The key feature is OMP reduction don't hesitate to read on that topic. https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/

```
      PROGRAM maxfunction
            double precision Maximum
            n1 = 10
            n2 = 20
            n3 = 30
            Maximum = -1000000.0
c$OMP PARALLEL DO DEFAULT(SHARED)
c$OMP+ SHARED(n1, n2, n3)
c$OMP+ PRIVATE(i,j, A, B, C, F)
c$OMP+ reduction(max: Maximum)
          Do i=0, n1
              A= i*1.0
              Do j=0, n2
                  B=j*1.0
                  Do k=0,n3
                      C=k*1.0
                      F=findF(A,B,C)
                      If( F > Maximum) Then 
                          Maximum= F
                       endif
                  Enddo
              Enddo
          Enddo 
c$OMP END PARALLEL DO
      print *, Maximum
      ENDPROGRAM
```

with

```
  function g1(a,b,c)
      g1 = a
  endfunction g1

  function g2(a,b,c)
      g2 = b
  endfunction g2

  function g3(a,b,c)
      g3 = -c
  endfunction g3
```

This code returns `30.0` whatever the number of threads