# OMP variable reduction inside subroutine called in the OMP block

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, fortran

I have a variable pointed to by this pointer in one of my routines:

```
complex(dp), pointer :: Pkc(:,:)=>NULL()
```

I also allocate it in the same routine:

```
call MIO_Allocate(Pkc,[1,1,1],[ptsTot,nAt,2],'Pkc','diag')
```

Inside this routine, I use it inside an OMP region:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(iee, ie, unfoldedK), REDUCTION(+:Ake1, Ake2, Ake), &  
!$OMP& SHARED(Pkc, KptsG, E, Kpts, AkeGaussian1, AkeGaussian2, AkeGaussian, nAt, nspin, is, ucell, gcell, H0, maxNeigh, hopp, NList, Nneigh, neighCell, gaussian, Epts) 
  do ik=1,ptsTot ! K loop
  ...
  call DiagSpectralWeightWeiKuInequivalentInequivalent(nAt,nspin,is,Pkc(ik,:,:),E(:,is),Kpts(:,ik),unfoldedK(:),ucell,gcell,H0,maxNeigh,hopp,NList,Nneigh,neighCell)
  ...
  end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

where the new routine that is called is given by

```
subroutineDiagSpectralWeightWeiKu(N,ns,is,PkcLoc,E,K,KG,cell,H0,maxN,hopp,N List,Nneigh,neighCell)
...
complex(dp), intent(out) :: PkcLoc(N,2)
...
do j=1,N ! These are the eigenvectors with band index J
do in=1,N
PkcLoc(j,1) = PkcLoc(j,1) + exp(-cmplx_i*dot_product(KG, RtsVec(in,:))) * Hts(in,j)
end do
end do
...
end subroutine DiagSpectralWeightWeiKuInequivalent
```

How can I make sure that PkcLoc gets the proper behavior when doing OMP? I am getting segmentation faults which I assume are related to a missing `REDUCTION` on PkcLoc.

Any advice on how to solve this?

I found this [thread,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347944/fortran-openmp-with-subroutines-and-functions) but it's different in the sense that in my case, the do loop is outside of the subroutine that is called.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]

Comment: As Vladimir points out, we can't say much without a working example. I'd like to mention already that by "slicing" `Pkc` as `Pkc(ik,:,:)` the content of the array `Pkc` is likely very slow as you use the "closest in memory" indexing to spread the data among the threads.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. As this is a vast code with a lot of dependencies and interactions, I'm trying to build the erratic behavior from scratch. For now, i have not been able to get the same segmentation, so my initial assumption on `Reduction` might be wrong. Will come back once I have more useful information.

Comment: Took me a while, but turns out the problem was something else. My code seems to be creating too many temporary arrays. I circumvent the issue by working on the heap using the  `-heap-arrays` compiler flag. Is that ok for omp threaded code?