# slow down of a parallel subroutine when called inside a loop

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have parallelized a subroutine. It have very good benchmark : speedup 4X on a quad core. I have them in two different source: serial.f and paral.f. The comparison is made running them from terminal and printing elapsed wall clock time. Inside each source code there is only call to the associate subroutine. But, when I modify the sources like this :

```
serial.f :

do i=1,100
    call serial
end do
```

and like this

```
 paral.f :

 do i=1,100
      call paral
 end do
```

performance goes down to 0.96 X speed: the parallel version is bad than the serial one! The code can be found in [why calling many N times a serial subroutine is faster than calling N times the parallel version of the same subroutin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716721/why-calling-many-n-times-a-serial-subroutine-is-faster-than-calling-n-times-the?noredirect=1#comment99997881_56716721)
For obtaining the serial.f just comment the block containing the call paral. For obtaining the paral.f just comment the block containing the call serial.
I'm asking : is this a common problem ? How can I solve it to maintain the 4 X speedup maintaning the loop call?
Please note : 
(1)I've tried translating to C and timing, benchmarks and problems remains all the same
(2) I've tried translating to modern fortran and timing, benchmarks and problems remains all the same
(3) I've tried all kind of tricks and rewriting of the code. I'm sure the problem is not how the subroutine is parallelized (I achieved 4 X ) but that it is called too many times inside a loop.
Thank you.

EDIT ::
As requested, I'm posting a program written in modern fortran who esibit the same issues :

```
program main


use omp_lib

implicit none

integer ( kind = 4 ), parameter :: m = 5000
integer ( kind = 4 ), parameter :: n = 5000
integer ( kind = 4 ) i
integer ( kind = 4 ) j
integer ( kind = 4 ) nn
real ( kind = 8 ) u(m,n)
real ( kind = 8 ) w(m,n)
real ( kind = 8 ) wtime,h

call random_seed()


do j=1,n
  do i=1,m
    call random_number(u(i,j))
  end do
end do


wtime = omp_get_wtime ( )

do nn=1,100

!$omp parallel do default(none) shared(u, w) private(i,j)

do j = 2, n - 1
  do i = 2, m - 1
    w(i,j) = 0.25D+00 * ( u(i-1,j) + u(i+1,j) + u(i,j-1) + u(i,j+1) )
  end do
end do

!$omp end parallel do

end do

wtime = omp_get_wtime ( ) - wtime



h=0.0D+00
do j=1,n
  do i=1,m
    h=h+w(i,j)
  end do
end do



write ( *, '(a,g14.6)' ) '  Wall clock time serial= ', wtime
write ( *, '(a,g14.6)' ) '  h ', h

stop
end
```

In order to get serial_with_loop.f90 just comment openmp directives and the nn loop. You must obtain also with a similar method parall_with_loop.f90 and serial and parall without loop. You can compile with " gfortran -o name.out -fopenmp -O3 name.f90 " and launch from terminal with output redirection to text file "name.out > time_result.txt"

Comment: Well in the code you link to you don't initialise any of the arrays you use, thus the code is wrong, thus all performance measures are meaningless. That's all I'll say until you rewrite it in a form more relevant to the 2010's than the 1980s, common and OpenMP in particular is just asking for a life of pain, as is using compiler flags to change the size of datatypes. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347944/fortran-openmp-with-subroutines-and-functions/35361665#35361665

Comment: @IanBush with inizialization all the problems remains the same.

Comment: @IanBush I posted a similar code with initialization , written in modern fortran.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you are parallelizing the loop on j that is located inside a loop on nn. Therefore, for each nn value, your machine needs time to create a pool of threads that do the job for different value of j. Therefore, this time (required for creating the pool) is serial and cannot be devided by the number of used threads. As I see your code, there is no reason for not being able to parallelize the nn loop and creating that pool only once, instead of nn times. I think that your code will work better if you write

```
 wtime = omp_get_wtime ( )
 !$omp parallel do default(none) shared(u, w) private(nn,i,j)
 do nn=1,100
   do j = 2, n - 1
     do i = 2, m - 1
       w(i,j) = 0.25D+00 * ( u(i-1,j) + u(i+1,j) + u(i,j-1) + u(i,j+1))
     end do
   end do
 end do
 !$omp end parallel do
 wtime = omp_get_wtime ( ) - wtime
```

I hope that this helps you.