# Possible race condition despite barrier at every step in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp, race-condition

I am trying to write a fortran application using openMP. I have extensive experience in MPI but still struggling with OMP syncronization. Please consider the following example:

```
module ps_mod

    contains
    subroutine cg(A,b,N)
        use iso_fortran_env
        implicit none
        real(real64)        :: A(:,:), b(:)
        integer(int32)      :: N

        integer                   :: i
        real(real64)              :: alpha
        real(real64), allocatable :: v(:), p0(:)


        allocate(v(N))
        allocate(p0(N))

        !$omp parallel shared(v,p0,A,b,i)
        v(:)   = 10000.
        alpha = 1.0_real64
        p0(:) = b(:)

        !$omp barrier
        call dotp(p0, v, alpha, N)
        !$omp barrier

        alpha = 10.0/alpha
        !$omp barrier

        print *, "alpha", alpha

        !$omp barrier
        !$omp end parallel

    end subroutine cg

    subroutine dotp(x,y,res,n)
        !res = sum(x*y)
        use iso_fortran_env
        implicit none
        integer(int32)  :: n, j
        real(real64)    :: x(n), y(n), res

        res=0.0_real64
        !$omp barrier
        !$omp do private(j) reduction(+:res)
        do j = 1, n
            res = res + x(j)*y(j)
        enddo
        !$omp barrier
    end subroutine dotp

end module ps_mod

!------------------------ main function
program main_omp
    use iso_fortran_env
    use ps_mod
    implicit none
    real(real64), allocatable           :: mat(:,:), y(:)
    integer(int32) :: n, i

    n = 8000
    allocate(mat(n, n))
    allocate(y(n))

    mat = 0.0_real64
    do i = 1,n
        mat(i,i) = 1.0_real64
    enddo
    y = 0.2_real64

    call cg(mat, y, n)
end program main_omp
```

It takes simple matrix and vector and performs some calculations on them, reducing the output in one variable alpha.

I compiled it using gfortran 7.3.1 `gfortran -O3 -fopenmp main_omp.f90` and ran with 5 threads using `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=5`; the output I am getting is changing between runs `for i in $(seq 1 20);do ./a.out ;done`.

```
...
 alpha   6.2500000000000005E-007
 alpha   15999999.999999998     
 alpha   15999999.999999998     
 alpha   15999999.999999998     
 alpha   15999999.999999998     
 alpha   15999999.999999998     
 alpha   6.2500000000000005E-007
 alpha   6.2500000000000005E-007
...
```

with lesser threads also its the same, but bit infrequent. However with single thread I always get the same result. hence iI do not think its some misallocated memory issue (in my main program I also tested with libasan and it says no leak). Therefore I believe its an open MP race condition but I cant diagnose where. As you can see I have explicitly give barriers everywhere.

---

Update:

After conversations with @Giles I was figured out that following construct does work if i use a dummy variable and explicitly make alpha private, but I do not know why.

```
real(real64)::s
!$omp parallel shared(v,p0,A,b,i) private(alpha)
        v(:)   = 10000.
        alpha = 1.0_real64
        p0(:) = b(:)

        !$omp barrier
        call dotp(p0, v, s, N) !<----- dummy s
        !$omp barrier
        alpha = s  !<------ assign dummy s value to private alpha
        !$omp barrier
        alpha = 10.0/alpha
```

Comment: Try removing all OpenMP directives from the `cg` subroutine, and replace the `!$omp do` with `!$omp parallel do` in the `dotp` subroutine (while also removing the unnecessary `!$omp barrier` there.

Comment: @Gilles Your suggestion does remove the supposed race condition, however it would not be useful for my program as in actual calculations, between the parallel regions, there are many workshare constructs too, and some other OMP paragmas. I was hoping to initialize omp parallel region once and gain any possible performance boost. If possible can you point out any obvious mistakes in above program? I have same program in MPI which worked fine.

Comment: you have race conditions wherever you have a shared variable which is written by more that one thread like `v(:)=10000.` If you really want to go for your kind of approach, then put the part that is logically sequential inside an `!$omp single` construct. But that is altogether quite painful to do and to maintain properly. You should first go for the simple approach of creating as many `parallel` regions as you need and only try to reduce them if/when you see some performance issue

Comment: I just checked, even if i enclose them in single construct, issue remain. the dotp function also always return correct value. and error only happens in "alpha = 10.0/alpha" statement. I dont know how, despite alpha being private (?) and sandwiched between  barrier constructs.

Comment: I have update with exact problem area and one working solution. but I would not know why is that happening, or what was happening before

Comment: Try scoping all your variables explicitly rather than relying on defaults. Does that clear up the issues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347944/fortran-openmp-with-subroutines-and-functions/35361665#35361665 might help as well. Also please don't use !$omp parallel do when learning the language, you have to separate the odeas od scoping and work sharing to properly understand what is going on.

Comment: @ipcamit In alpha = 10.0/alpha if alpha is shared you are reading from and writing to a shared object with no synchronisation point. This can lead to a race condition. Just because they are on the same line by default there is no well defined ordering of the accesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a synchronisation at every line, but you don't have a synchronisation between every memory access, and that is what you need to be absolutely sure of ordering. In particular the line

```
alpha = 1.0 / alpha
```

Has multiple threads read from and writing to a shared variable possibly at the same time; there is no ordering of the memory accesses just because they are on the same line. A simple example:

```
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ cat race.f90 
Program in_line_racing

  Implicit None

  Real :: alpha, s

  alpha = 3.0

  !$omp parallel default( none ) shared( alpha ) private( s )
  alpha = 1.0 / alpha
  s = alpha
  Write( *, * ) s
  !$omp end parallel

End Program in_line_racing
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ gfortran -fopenmp race.f90 
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ ./a.out 
  0.333333343    
  0.333333343    
  0.333333343    
   3.00000000    
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ ./a.out 
   3.00000000    
   3.00000000    
  0.333333343    
  0.333333343    
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ ./a.out 
   3.00000000    
   3.00000000    
  0.333333343    
  0.333333343    
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ ./a.out 
   3.00000000    
  0.333333343    
   3.00000000    
  0.333333343    
ijb@LAPTOP-GUG8KQ9I:~/work/stack$ ./a.out 
   3.00000000    
  0.333333343    
  0.333333343    
  0.333333343
```

You need the result of the reduction to be a shared variable, so your updated version works because you first make sure the reduced variable is completely up to date on all threads, and then perform the inverse on a private variable which can't suffer race conditions.

Welcome to threaded programming. Bugs are very easy!

Comment: I miss MPI! most race conditions could be solved by liberally applying MPI_Barrier!

Comment: I would also like to add that I just found out that like address sanitizer we have thread sanitizer too. if libtsan is installed one can compile with `-fsanitize=thread -static-libtsan` and it highlighted several race conditions in my program

Comment: Your assignments to v and p0 are still races. Every thread is assigning to the whole of each array. Since they're all assigning the same values it's not likely to cause a crash, but is formally incorrect, and is performing more work than is required. At a higher level, why are you not using a BLAS library for this? It will include many more optimisations (vectorisation, cache-blocking), and you don't have to write it...

Answer (score 0):

Before:

```
    !$omp parallel shared(v,p0,A,b,i)
    v(:)   = 10000.     ! race, write to shared v(:)
    alpha = 1.0_real64  ! race, write to shared alpha 
    p0(:) = b(:)        ! race, write to shared p0(:)

    !$omp barrier
    call dotp(p0, v, alpha, N) ! not race, reduction(+:res)
    !$omp barrier

    alpha = 10.0/alpha  ! race, write to shared alpha
    !$omp barrier

    print *, "alpha", alpha, loc(alpha), loc(v(1)), loc(p0(1))
```

After:

```
    real(real64)::s
    !$omp parallel shared(v,p0,A,b,i) private(alpha)
    v(:)   = 10000.     ! race, write to shared v(:)
    alpha = 1.0_real64  ! not race, write to private alpha
    p0(:) = b(:)        ! race, write to shared p0(:)

    !$omp barrier
    call dotp(p0, v, s, N) ! not race, reduction(+:res)
    !$omp barrier
    alpha = s           ! not race, write to private alpha
    !$omp barrier       ! barrier don't needed
    alpha = 10.0/alpha  ! not race, write to private alpha
```

Race in "v(:) =", "p0(:) =" and "res=0.0_real64" - writing the same values repeatedly only results in performance losses.

Comment: I have actually mentioned in the comments that this was supposed to be in a workshare construct. for posting the question I scrubbed out lot of code and removed the workshare construct too.