# Call Fortran subroutine in a OpenMP parallel region?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I am trying to call a subroutine inside the main OpenMP parallel region like:

```
type(type1) :: A(:)
!$omp parallel private(variable_a, variable_b, ...)
!$do
do i = 1, n, 1
  call A(i) % sub(variable_a, variable_b, ...)
end do
$enddo
!$end parallel
```

In another file, I define the Fortran type `type1`, which contains a procedure named `sub`. The `sub` is like:

```
subroutine( this, val_a, val_b, ...)
  class(type1), intent(inout) :: this
  type(anytype), intent(in) :: val_a
  type(anytype), intent(in) :: val_b
  ...

  ! type_2 is another type defined in another file
  type(type2), pointer :: p => null

  do i = 1, n, 1
    allocate(p)
    p => null()
  end do

return
end subroutine
```

However, I found that the `p` seems is a shared variable. Why it happens?

Comment: I output ```associated(p)``` before ```allocated(p)```, and sometimes it prints True

Comment: WIthout a [mre] it's really not possible to say anything useful, I'm afraid. It would be useful to see the code where you "output `associated(p)` before `allocated(p)`.

Comment: Unless there is an exception for pointers that I am not aware of p should be shared. This is because p has an initialisation expression, as such has the save attribute, and local variables with the save attribute are shared in orphaned subroutines - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347944/fortran-openmp-with-subroutines-and-functions/35361665#35361665

Comment: Is that `=> null` standard-conforming or is that a compiler extension? I thought `NULLIFY` was the way to, eh, nullify a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Following the OpenMP standard `p` should be shared as it has an initialization and is not part of a threadprivate directive. Quoting from section 5.1.2 in [the OpenMP 5.2 standard document](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/OpenMP-API-Specification-5-2.pdf):

> Local variables declared in called routines in the region and that
> have the SAVE attribute, or that are data initialized, are shared
> unless they appear as arguments in a threadprivate directive.

Comment: Wow So it's the null initialization of the pointer that trips up the OP....

Comment: The good old http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#4

Comment: An unusual variant, but yes!

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава It should not surprise me, having grown up with F66 and every variable being global and `SAVE`d, but somehow it does.